# The initialization of static variables in C

Tags: c, static, struct, initialization

I have a question about the initialization of static variables in C. I know if we declare a global static variable that by default the value is `0`. For example:

```
static int a; //although we do not initialize it, the value of a is 0
```

but what about the following data structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Hello;

static Hello hello[3];
```

are all of the members in each struct of `hello[0]`, `hello[1]`, `hello[2]` initialized as `0`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, all members are initialized for objects with static storage. See 6.7.8/10 in the [C99 Standard (PDF document)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly**, then:
>   — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>   — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules.

To initialize everything in an object, whether it's `static` or not, to 0, I like to use the *universal zero initializer*

```
sometype identifier0 = {0};
someothertype identifier1[SOMESIZE] = {0};
anytype identifier2[SIZE1][SIZE2][SIZE3] = {0};
```

---

There is no *partial initialization* in C. An object either is fully initialized (to `0` of the right kind in the absence of a different value) or not initialized at all.
If you want partial initialization, you can't initialize to begin with.

```
int a[2]; // uninitialized
int b[2] = {42}; // b[0] == 42; b[1] == 0;
a[0] = -1; // reading a[1] invokes UB
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more this line? `a[0] = -1;`

Comment: It is simple assignment. After `a` was defined (and left uninitialized) reading either `a[0]` or `a[1]` invokes UB. After the assignment to `a[0]` you can safely read from there, but not from `a[1]`.

Comment: What does "UB" mean?

Comment: **UB** is Undefined Behaviour. See, eg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are, as long they have static or thread storage duration.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.7.9 Initialization #10**
>
> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> [...]
>
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>     and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> [...]

Comment: The [draft of the C11 Standard (PDF document)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is freely available online.

Comment: "All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before program startup." (5.1.2.2.2 in the c99 pdf)

Which addresses my semi-related question.  If you use a static variable because you want it to retain its value (like for a running total) across function calls should you manually initialize it to 0?  No.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, file-scope static variables are initialized to zero, including all members of structures, arrays, etc.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398609/212858) for reference (I'll vote to close this as a duplicate, too).

---

Edit: this question is getting much better answers, so I'm voting to close *that* question as a duplicate of *this*, instead.

For reference, here is the [C FAQ link](http://c-faq.com/decl/initval.html) from that question's accepted answer, although of course the C99 and C11 standards linked here are canonical.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that static variables (or arrays) are classified into two types.

**Initialized** are the ones that are given value from code at compile time. These are usually stored in DS though this is compiler specific.

The other type is **uninitialized** statics which are initialized at run time and are stored into BSS segment though again this is compiler specific.

[BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who don't want to read the standard, it's also mentioned in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization :

> Implicit initialization
>
> If an initializer is not provided:
>
> - objects with automatic storage duration are initialized to indeterminate values (which may be trap representations)
> - **objects with static and thread-local storage duration are zero-initialized**