# What is the default value of a char in an uninitialized array, in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization

Given the following declaration:

`char inputBuffer[12];`

What is the default value of either char within the array?
I'm interested in knowing this because if at any time I want to clear a position in the array, I need to know what value to give it.

Comment: it depends where the array is declared. .e.g in a function it will be garbage in there, in the BSS it will be set to 0. Just have look at the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Comment: possible duplicate of [The initialization of static variables in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251083/the-initialization-of-static-variables-in-c)

Comment: It is called uninitialized because it is not initialized. If there was a defined default value, it would be called default-initialized. To clear a position in an array you have to do exactly nothing.

Comment: n.m. "To clear a position in an array you have to do exactly nothing." - not sure that's a meaningful or useful perspective... to have a notion of "clearing" values you have to either select a *sentinel* value that will be *deemed* clear/unused etc., or keep some separate, additional record of which indices are "clear".

Comment: " I'm interested in knowing this because if at any time I want to clear a position in the array, I need to know what value to give it." -- That makes no sense. Give it the value you want it to have.

Comment: @TonyD If a position in its uninitialized state considered cleared, then it is cleared in any other state, there's no need to do anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The array elements have indeterminate value except if the array it is defined at file-scope or have `static` storage-class specifier then the array elements are initialized to `0`.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 char inputBuffer1[12];          // elements initialized to 0
 static char inputBuffer2[12];   // elements initialized to 0

 void foo(void)
 {
     char inputBuffer3[12];         // elements have indeterminate value!
     static char inputBuffer4[12];  // elements initialized to 0
 }
```

Comment: In my scenario, the variable is global, so they're initialized to 0.
If I were to "clear" the value of an array element, that would mean passing it 0, right?

Comment: @AndreiOniga if you want to have an array explicitly initialized to 0 (to avoid indeterminate value): at declaration time, `char inputBuffer3[12] = {0};`, after it has been declared use `memset`.

Answer (score 10):

If `char inputBuffer[12];` is global or static, it is initialized with `\0`

```
char inputBuffer1[12];  /* Zeroed */
static char inputBuffer1[12];  /* Zeroed */

int fn()
{
  static char inputBuffer3[12];  /* Zeroed */
}
```

If it is local to function, it contains garbage value.

```
int fn2()
{
  char inputBuffer4[12];  /* inderminate value */
}
```

Quoting from **ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 Committee Draft — May 6, 2005 WG14/N1124**

Section **6.7.8 Initialization** (emphasis mine)

> 10 If an object that has **automatic** storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
> — if it has
>   pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; 
> — if it has
>   arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; 
> —
>   if it is an **aggregate**, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules; 
> — if it is a union, the first named member
>   is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.