# Why does my code print out some garbage from my array?

Tags: c, string, stdout

I am currently learning C, and I want to create a function that reverses an input. Here is the piece of code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char input[100];

while(1) {
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

        for(int i = 99; i > -1; i--) {
            printf("%c", input[i]);
        }

    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The output of this is correct, but it also prints some garbage in between and I don't understand why. Can someone explain this to me?

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Rather than starting from `i = 99`, you have to figure out how many characters you got and start from that amount - 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default value of a char in an uninitialized array, in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797860/what-is-the-default-value-of-a-char-in-an-uninitialized-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should clear memory before using it.

Secondly, always keep one char with 'NULL' value at the end of a string. (only an option for your case, because you are not using `sprintf`, `strcpy`... and so on.)

Thirdly the `for` loop should start at the end of the input, that is `strlen(input)` which is located on `<string.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char input[100];

while(1) {
    memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));    // add memset() to clear memory before using it
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    for(int i = strlen(input); i > -1; i--) {
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuanhui explained it pretty good, so I'll just provide some improvement on his code:

```
int main() { // No need for argc and argv unless you use them
char input[100] = {0}; // Simpler than memset

do {
    // Security risk if you decide to change the size of input, so use
    // sizeof input instead of hard coded value. Also, check return value.
    if(!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) { /* Error handling code */ }

    // Overkill to use printf for a single char
    for(int i = strlen(input); i > -1; i--) putchar(input[i]);
    putchar('\n');
} while(!feof(stdin)) // End the loop on EOF
}
```