# Initializing a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, dynamic

So I have these statements in my code(there are many other lines but this is giving me trouble):

```
int *vector1;

if (vector1 == NULL)
    {

    }
```

When I try to run it it says "uninitialized local variable 'vector1' used"
If I put "&vector1 == NULL" it doesn't complain but also doesn't work correctly.

I really don't understand why I am getting this error. I want it to do something if vector1 doesn't point to anything.

Comment: &vector1 is never null.  why don't you just initialize vector1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *vector1 = NULL;
if (vector1 == NULL)
{

}
```

will work fine

```
int *vector1 = nullptr;
if (vector1 == nullptr)
{

}
```

Also works if you want to be a bit more up to date.

Pointers are not set to NULL by default. The answer why is here:
[Why aren't pointers initialized with NULL by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default)

Comment: of course, that (vector1==NULL) is always true...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, I thought when pointers were created they inherently pointed to NULL?

Comment: No that is not true, they will point to garbage data. I have udpated my post with a link to as why.

Answer (score 1):

The warning `uninitialized local variable 'vector1' used` tells you that you're using `vector1` even though you haven't initialized it. Therefore, its value might be anything.

Pointers (non-`static` ones) are ***not*** default-initialized to `0`. They are initialized with random junk data.

If you want to initialize it with `0`, `NULL`, or `nullptr` ([all the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c)):

```
int *vector1 = 0; // or NULL, or nullptr.
```

Comment: static variables are initialized to zero http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251083/the-initialization-of-static-variables-in-c

Comment: @RichardChambers yea